# RRDtool and left horizontal scale formatting

Tags: rrdtool

Im learning RRDtool. I created a graph:

```
#!/bin/bash

rrdtool graph /home/pi/rrd/test.png \
    --end now --start now-6000s --width 500 --height 400 \
    DEF:ds0a=/home/pi/rrd/temperature.rrd:temperature:AVERAGE \
    AREA:ds0a#0000FF:"Temperature ('C)\l" \
```

It looks like this:

[image]

**How can I format scale to add fractional part?**

I want 25.2, 25.4, 25.6 etc. instead of 25 few times.

I have tried option from RRDtool documentation online

```
--left-axis-format
```

but my RRDtool has no such option.

There is no problem with

```
--right-axis-format
```

it works as I want, but... I want correct format on left side, not right.

Im using 1.4.7 on Raspberry Pi. I was asking on unix.stackexchange.com about this, but there are more questions about RRDtool here, so I moved my question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later versions of RRDTool handle the axis labelling a bit better than earlier ones, so an upgrade might be all that is needed to fix it.

The first thing to try is `--alt-y-grid` option which changes the default way the Y-axis labels are placed.  This might solve your issue.

You can override the automatic Y-axis calculations using something like `--y-grid 0.2:5` which will put a tick every 0.2 but only label every 5 ticks, IE at 25, 26, 27 and so on.  This will give you a sane but sparsely populated Y-axis.

However, maybe you want a label at every line, but including the decimals.  In this case, you can specify the formatting of the Y-axis labels to include a decimal place: `--left-axis-format "%.1lf"` .  You say that your version does not support this, so you might like to consider upgrading.

Comment: With --alt-y-grid numbers responsible for 25.2 etc. just disappear. There is no 1.4.8 version for raspberry, I can't compile new one because there is no cairo_png cairo_pdf and few other librariers for arm/raspberry... :( I don't want to compile 50 things to handle formatting...

Comment: I think the left-axis-format option was added in the later version to address precisely this problem - since it uses 0dp if the y-axis number is >1, which causes the problem you see.
If you can't recompile the latest version, then I'd suggest using --y-grid to at least hide the duplicated labels.  I don't think there is any way to achieve exactly what you want with your version of rrdtool.

Comment: I have tried to compile 1.4.8 (current version), but I have so many warnings and errors from ./configure script, that I gave up. I will use pChart or something else for charting. RRD graph functionality is not that versatile I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed rrdtool 1.4.8 on Raspbian using the testing branch.  Unfortunately, the --left-axis-format option isn't available in 1.4.8 either.  I could see in GIT where the code for --left-axis-format was added but my GIT foo isn't strong enough to figure out what version it was merged with.

**Update: --left-axis-format wasn't added until 1.4.9 according to the changelog:**

## RRDtool 1.4.9 - 2014-09-29

### New Features

- allows rrdrestore to read input from stdin
- add documentation for RRDs::xport
- RPN operators MINNAN and MAXNAN
- --**left-axis-format option to rrd_graph**

Updated update: I was able to easily compile rrdtool 1.4.9 from source just following the instructions in the included doc/rrdbuild.pod instruction file.